# Core Spotlight, continueUserActivity in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiapplication, corespotlight, nsuseractivity

iOS 9.2, xCode 7.2, Objective-C

I used this tutorial (Core Spotlight version) but translated it into Objective-C:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-introducing-search-apis--cms-24375

Everything works except one thing - I can't get callback when user taps the search result. It seems I need to write the following method in my app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *restorableObjects))restorationHandler
```

But it is not called at all. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to first check your activity has type search action :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void(^)(NSArray * __nullable restorableObjects))restorationHandler 
{
    if ([[userActivity activityType] isEqualToString:CSSearchableItemActionType]) 
    {
        NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [userActivity.userInfo objectForKey:CSSearchableItemActivityIdentifier];
        NSLog(@"%@",uniqueIdentifier);
        // Launch Detail controller
    }
return YES;
}
```

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: look at the question more attentively - I've already answered that it is not called. The only idea I have is this tutorial is partially incorrect and this method is called for `NSUserActivity`, not `Core Spotlight` which means at least I can't define multiple objects to handle (for example if I wrote browser then I can run this browser but can't view in spotlight multiple pages from history and can't allow user to go to any of them

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov Sorry!! Now i edited the answer. You have to implement different method in objective c.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it later. But the only thing I still can't understand is you call `[userActivity becomeCurrent]` so you have only one "activity" at the same time. But what if I need for example a queue of 3 last activities? Or should `Core Spotlight` call this method even without explicit `NSUserActivity` declaration.

Comment: finally solved it. The app I edit is not my own and there are several app delegates and only one inherits `UIApplicationDelegate` I need.